# php function only works when using customiser in wordpress - does not work when using front end

Tags: woocommerce

I am using a function I found on bbloomer(Rudolfo) site. "Truncate **short description** on single product page". However its approach is based on the short-desciption.php file in woocommerce. In that file the Class has already been added by woocommerce and works with this function when tested on my site everywhere. I don't use the short description for this site so wanted to apply it to the tabbed product description...since my tabs are exposed(always show) and not actually a tab.

To make it work with "description" (description.php file) I added custom class and matched it with the code. It worked and shows a "show more" button you can click and then shows the rest of the description. **The Problem:** It only works when testing it from backend in wordpress customizer, when using/verifying from front end...it shows the "show more" button and is highlited blue but....cannot click on it and does not respond.

I have tried 3 different browsers and all same result.

To add the snippet I used code snippets plugin.

Custom Class added to the descrition.php page directly: note: found in single product-> tabs folder -> descrition.php

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__description">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

**note: the new custom class I used**

```
woocommerce-product-details__description
```

**This is the Snippet I am using and edited to match the class:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product',
'bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more' );

function bbloomer_woocommerce_short_description_truncate_read_more() { 
   wc_enqueue_js('
    var show_char = 100;
    var ellipses = "... ";
    var content = $(".woocommerce-product-details__description").html();
  if (content.length > show_char) {
     var a = content.substr(0, show_char);
     var b = content.substr(show_char - content.length);
     var html = a + "<span class=\'truncated\'>" + ellipses + "<a class=\'read-more\'>Show more</a></span><span class=\'truncated\' style=\'display:none\'>" + b + "</span>";
     $(".woocommerce-product-details__description").html(html);
  }
  $(".read-more").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".woocommerce-product-details__description .truncated").toggle();
      });
   ');
}
```

**Note: the code snippet plugin has options for where to run the code and I always select "everywhere". You can run it only on backend but that is not the case for me.**
Does anyone have an idea how to gt this to work on front end aswell? I have never encountered this type of issue.

Thank you in advance for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: was a CSS overlap issue. I had however given the z-index: 1 and had forgotten about that telling myself it would be on top meaning issue should have been elsewhere. Well, its solved. I will leave this posted so others can modify this code as well like i had to work with the description.php file and not just the short-description.php file.

Thank you for reading :)